# glibc 2.18 configure warning

Tags: glibc, utorrent

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I'm trying to install `glibc-2.18` while `./configure` it gives

```
configure: error: you must configure in a separate build directory
```

Then I tried to configure in directory `bla` then it keeps repeating these lines :

```
checking build system type... (cached) x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... (cached) x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for dummy-gcc... (cached) gcc
checking for suffix of object files... (cached) o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for dummy-readelf... (cached) readelf
checking for sysdeps preconfigure fragments... x86_64 
configure: running configure fragment for add-on bla
configure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target
configure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target
```

`I'm originally trying to install`utorrent-server` which gives :

```
./utserver: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version GLIBC_2.16 not found (required by ./utserver)
```

How to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

You should build glibc on another directory instead of glibc source directory.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like:

```
# mkdir  build-tree
# cd  build-tree
# ../configure
```

This is going to enable you to configure (and build) glibc.

For glibc Ubuntu official build they do the same on debian/rules file.